# numpy reshape 2d matrix to 3d matrix by stacking columns

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy matrix with shape `(x,y)`. I want to get a tensor which is a vertical stack of `y` vectors with shape `(x,1)`.
Lets say I have the following matrix:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

when I do `np.reshape(2,3,1)`. I will get:

```
array([[[ 1.],
        [ 2.],
        [ 1.]],
       [[ 2.],
        [ 1.],
        [ 2.]]])
```

but I want this:

```
array([[[ 1.],
        [ 1.],
        [ 1.]],
       [[ 2.],
        [ 2.],
        [ 2.]]])
```

Comment: You mean `mat.reshape(x, 1, y)`?  Did you try it?

Comment: that is not what I want. I want a tensor of `((x,1),y)`

Comment: Please show example code and how the result differs from what you want.

Comment: lets say the matrix has shape `(x,2)`. I want to have a tensor with vertical stacks of `(x,1)`, that is the two columns stack vertically.

Comment: Show us code, with example data, example output, and how the example output differs from your desired output.

Comment: @JohnZwinck just edited the question

Comment: You say you want to turn shape `(x, y)` into shape `(x, 1, y)`, but then you call `reshape(2, 3, 1)`? And your input has shape `(3, 2)`. None of this is consistent. It's quite likely that if you get what you're asking for, you won't want it. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @user2357112 I edited the question. Hope its more clear.

Comment: That's clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [135]: arr=np.array([[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]])
In [136]: arr.shape
Out[136]: (3, 2)
In [137]: arr.transpose()
Out[137]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
In [138]: arr.transpose()[:,:,None]
Out[138]: 
array([[[1],
        [1],
        [1]],

       [[2],
        [2],
        [2]]])
```

You want a shape (2,3,1).  Starting with (3,2), that means you have to switch the 2 axes, and add one.  That can be done in either order.  Here I choose transpose to do the switch, and `[:,:,None]` to add the dimension.

`arr.reshape(3,2,1).swapaxes(0,1)` also works.  More obscurely, `np.stack(arr[:,:,None],1)`.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I think the trick was to only transpose the matrix.